# Fetch SQL Server stored procedure output results into table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried some solutions from the internet but they are not working for me .

My task is to get the out put of stored procedure into a table.The data is being inserted inside a  cursor by loop . I am creating temporary table to store and display the data.

My code:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[usp_Test]
AS
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   declare @caseId int;
   declare  @CHG_ID int;
   declare @HEAR_ID int;

   SET @CHG_ID = 1
   set @testid = 1;

   DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
     SELECT C_CASE_ID
     FROM table1     // tHERE WILL BE MULTIPLE CASEIDS    

   -- here I am trying to delete the temporary table, but it does not work
   IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##test_temp_table') IS NOT NULL 
      TRUNCATE TABLE ##test_temp_table
   ELSE
      CREATE TABLE test_temp_table(HEAR_ID int)

   OPEN db_cursor 

   FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @caseId 

   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
   BEGIN    
      insert into test_temp_table 
        EXEC STOREDPROCTEST2 @caseId, 1, @HEAR_ID OUTPUT;

      -- LOOP THROUGH THE CURSOR TO GET ALL     CASE IDS
      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @caseId 

      SELECT HEAR_ID FROM test_temp_table;
   END   

   CLOSE db_cursor  
   DEALLOCATE db_cursor;
```

I have two issues:

1. I cannot delete the temporary table
2. I am not seeing any output from the temporary table

Comment: As a starting observation, you mostly are referring to `test_temp_table`, which isn't a temporary table no matter what you name it, and despite the fact that you check for a global temp table named `##test_temp_table` using that `OBJECT_ID()` statement. Which are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

`[##test_temp_table]` and `[test_temp_table]` are two different tables.  First one is a global temp table, second one is a user table.  I believe you want to replace the user table with the global temp table, i.e. replace object `[test_temp_table]` with `[##test_temp_table]`.  or vice versa.  In the end, you have to ensure you are querying the correct table.

Comment: AHiggins ,can you also show how to insert the data into the table from the stored proc